# Bitwise negation check

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I was reading JS manual, and found nice trick, that `~val === (val != -1)`.
I found it nice, and want to use it in my C code.

Is it portable? I checked on my GNU/Linux box, it work.

EDIT: Seems I asked not too clearly. Of course, I know, there is no `===` in C.
Question is, are both conditionals

```
int val;
if (~val) {...}
if (val != -1) {...}
```

equal?

Comment: You must mean ~val === (val ^= -1)

Comment: what if val is -1 then your sentence is wrong..!!

Comment: Use `~val` in your code so that wouldn't confuse anybody.

Comment: Or if the right side is correct, then `!!~val === (val!=-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following answer was written for the question as it was originally phrased, which led myself and others to think that he was asking whether `~ans` and `(ans ^ -1)` are equivalent.**

This trick is not as portable as `~val` because it assumes that `-1 == 0b111111111...`, which is true only on a two's complement machine (granted, that holds for virtually any machine today). It exploits the fact that the xor operation works as a "controlled inverter", flipping  each bit in its left operand for which the corresponding right operand bit is one.

However, substituting `~0` for `-1` might work.

Comment: Nice idea. But I think `~0` is not garantied to be negative,right?

Comment: Alas, the point is not to make it negative but to generate the bit pattern of all ones, which I believe ~0 will always accomplish. :)

Comment: It all about functions like `indexOf`. Also, on what kinds of computers it actually fails? Is integer representation depends on kernel, compiler, hardware?

Comment: It depends on the hardware architecture. As far as I know two's complement is used almost universally today.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

First, the operator "===" doesn't exist i C.
Secondly, the comparison "val != -1" returns true (1) or false (0) in C.

What is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: He's using "===" to mean equivalency. And he wants to flip all bits in  the value binary, which Aki's comment will do.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of `if (exprA) vs if (exprB)`,
`exprA := ~val`,
`exprB := val!=-1`
they are equal.

In the context of (exprA) and (exprB) evaluating to the same value, the answer is No.

Either
`exprA := ~val` in which case the equivalent expression is
`exprB := val ^ -1`,  or

`exprB := val!=-1`, in which case the equivalent expression could be
`exprA := !!(~val)`

The revised question is different, as (val!=-1) evaluates to either 0 or 1 in numerical values, but if statements can use any non-zero value to represent the condition true.

So the answer depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

val != -1 will either be 1 or 0.

```
If val = 0,  ~0 = 0xFFFFFFFF on a 32 bit machine with 32 bit integer.
If val = 1,  ~1 = 0xFFFFFFFE on a 32 bit machine with 32 bit integer.
```

and so on.

HOW in the world would this be equal to 1 or 0? anything but only for two specific values of 'val'?

According to Aki's statement: you probably meant ~val = val ^= -1.

```
xor truth table:
 --------------------
|A   |   B   |  A^B |
 --------------------
|0   |   0   |  0   | 
 --------------------
|0   |   1   |  1   |
 --------------------
|1   |   0   |  1   |
 --------------------
|1   |   1   |  0   |
 --------------------
example: val = 1:
1(val) is represented as : 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
-1 is represented as:      1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
-------------------------------------------------------------------
         (XOR VAL AND -1): 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[negate:0to1 1to0]  ~val : 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Since these two are logically equal - and all machines follow logic, this has to work on every machine that stores negative number in 2's complement method.

BTW: 2's complement is 1's complement of a negative number + 1:

hence to store -1:

```
-1 = negative     :   0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
1' = 1s compliment:   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
2' = 2s compliemnt:   1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
---------------------------------------------------------------
```